# Send custom data along with music (MP3) in iOS via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth

**AIM:** I am trying to integrate my iPhone app with a bluetooth device that can play music and display some visualisation (yet to choose bluetooth hardware). There are three things that puzzles me:

1. I have seen some sample programs that generate visualisation data based on averagePowerForChannel using AVAudioPlayer. Is it possible to extract such information for a music stored in iPhone filesystem without actually (or before) playing the music? Since iPhone apps cannot execute in background infinitely, extracting this data realtime may not advised?
2. Once I create this "visualisation" data for an mp3, can how can I send the data to my bluetooth device? I know we can sent custom data only via BLE. Is there a possibility that I can send music data and visualisation data to the bluetooth device at the same time?(or sent visualisation data for a few seconds first and then start streaming the music) - This advice will help me to choose a proper hardware, provided iPhone supports this!
3. If I cannot sent music data and visualisation data at the same time over bluetooth, I am planning to extract visualisation data first from the mp3(how?), send it over to be stored in the bluetooth device and then display accordingly, in sync with the music data received in real time. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe this hardware has the capability I require: http://www.ti.com/tool/cc256xqfnem?DCMP=ecs-cc256x-em-board&HQS=ecs-CC256X-em-board-pf-bn#descriptionArea

Comment: You made a lot of wrong assumptions.  For example:  I know we can sent custom data only via BLE.  Do research on networking via bluetooth on iOS.  Break down your research on individual topic: averagePowerForChannel, sending data via bluetooth, etc.